# SlideJS - Remove the ease-in effect

Tags: slider, slideshow, slide

I am using SlideJs (http://www.slidesjs.com/) slideshow in my project.

Here, I wanted to have a repetitive image which will slide left. Right now, I have set the interval to '0' so that the slideshow just moves left without any interval. But the problem here is I don't want that ease-in effect which gives a pause. Just wanted to make the slideshow slide left continuously so that my repetitive background looks like flowing smoothly towards left.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/vc9w4/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a few patch on your fiddle, that you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vc9w4/6/

First, get the new version of the plugin in the Fiddle,
Then just set up your Slider with the new options for the speed easing control:

```
$(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
          effect: {
              slide: {
                  easing: {
                      animate: 'linear', // 'linear' or 'swing'
                      CSS3: 'linear' // 'linear' or 'ease' or anything you want: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp
                  }
              }
          }
     });
});
```

Just notice that this slider is using CSS3 properties for animation when they are available, and that the easing options are not the same between CSS3 TransitionTimingFunction and jQuery animate, so you have 2 parameters to manage in order to keep the compatibility for old browsers.

Comment: Now, the responsive stuff is broken when re sizing :(

Comment: Hummm what do you mean by "broken" ?
In fact, as long as it is using CSS3 properties, the animation take care of the animation time, so the resizing is running with this timing !
But I did not change something on the "update" method of the Slider,  do you see a difference between your JSFiddle and the one I gave you, updated ?